# Self Update in .net programs?

Tags: c#, .net

I`m looking for best mechanism for self update in .net programs!
solution should cover this subject:
1) Server - Client Program
2) When new update released, after installing that on the sever-program, all client-program must update itself base on server version.(no need automatic-update for server)
3) Full-Update : for example if server on version 3 and last update package version is 5, update package must contain any older package.

Comment: Both of these solution is working well, but I chose Barry answer cuz this is simplest solution

Comment: Also if anyone looking for better solution must check this
.NET Client Applications: .NET Application Updater Component

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you looked in to [Click Once deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d(VS.80).aspx)?

Comment: You would have to choose a deployment option, probably via a web server in this case.  Then when you publish the application you can set options such as the version and what should happen to previous versions of the application.  You can also set options as to whether the application installs on the machine locally or is run from a temp location on the local machine and then removed once the application is closed.  There is a lot of information relating to Click Once and you should read up fully before implementing it.  There isn't going to a quick one line answer to your question.

Comment: There is a nice tutorial here:   

http://weblogs.asp.net/shahar/archive/2008/01/29/how-to-use-clickonce-to-deploy-your-applications.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with this component: [.NET Client Applications: .NET Application Updater Component](http://windowsclient.net/articles/appupdater.aspx)